# relation between two gaussian vectors.

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

suppose I have two vector of unequal length, $X =\left \{  x_1, x_2, ... x_n  \right \}$ and $Y =\left \{  y_1, y_2, ... y_m  \right \}$ . Each element follows the same gaussian distribution , elements within the same vector are independent, however, there are $k$ disjoint pairs $\left \{ (i_1, j_1 ), (i_2,j_2), ... (i_k, j_k) \right \}$such that possible $X_{i_t} = Y_{j_t}$, by disjoint, I mean, all the $2k$ integers are distinct.

If the length are the same, I think the covariance is able to tell me some information about the dependance.

What are the statistical measure the tells me how strong they are related with respect to $k$? what test can I run to find out the number $k$ ( approximately) ?  Is the problem easier if the distribution isn't Gaussian?

Thanks

Comment: You mean that is not possible to have $X_1 = Y_1$ because it would imply that the $2k$ integers are _not_ distinct (since two of them have the same value $1$). Is there is some loss of generality if you assume that $X_i=Y_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$?

Comment: good point, but I don't know the position where they could be equal. Limiting only the first ones can be the same makes the problem easier. I guess a random shuffle is needed.